# Third law of thermodynamics - A contradiction?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

The third law of thermodynamics states that a system in equilibrium has entropy $\to$ 0, as its temperature $\to$ 0, which essentially means the system is in ground state.  However consider the case of particles in a box or simple harmonic oscillators at $T = 0$, or in the absence of a bath. Naively it seems that these systems can be excited at any particular energy level while the temperature is fixed, and therefore the entropy is non-zero. Why is the third law even valid in this case?

Comment: When you make an excitation, you are adding energy to the system, in other words you are heating it, the temperature goes up. But maybe I did not understand the question, maybe this is a question of what temperature is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider your case of $N$ simple harmonic oscillators, each of which has energy $E_i = N_i+ \frac{1}{2}$. The total energy of the system is given by

$$E = \sum_i E_i = \sum_i N_i+ \frac{N}{2}$$
while the number of energy quanta distributed is given by

$$Q = \sum_i N_i.$$

The number of microstates accessible to these harmonic oscillators is

$$\Omega (E,N) = \frac{(Q + N -1)!}{Q!(N-1)!} = \frac{(E + N/2 -1)!}{(E-N/2)!(N-1)!}.$$

You can show using Stirling approximation that

$$S = Nk_B \left[ \left( E/N + 1/2\right) \log \left( E/N + 1/2\right) - \left( E/N - 1/2\right) \log \left( E/N - 1/2\right) \right].$$

The temperature is found out to be

$$\frac{1}{T} = \frac{\partial S}{\partial E} = k_b \log \left(\frac{E/N + 1/2}{E/N -1/2} \right)$$

from which the energy density is given by

$$\frac{E}{N} = \frac{1}{2} \coth \left[ \frac{1}{2k_bT}\right].$$

You can easily check here that if $T \to 0$, then $E \to \frac{N}{2}$, and consequently the entropy goes to zero. Similar calculation will apply for a particle in box also with $T \to 0$, then $E \to E_0$ and $S \to 0$, where $NE_0$ is the ground state energy. Thus the third law isn't violated in both cases.

Comment: @BruceLee This is fine. However I can excite a large number of oscillators at $T=0$ in a number of ways. Isn't the entropy finitely non-zero then?

Comment: Also you say " As $T \to 0$, then $E \to \frac{N}{2}"$. What I am saying is that even at $T \to 0$, there can be excited states of the system. In that case why does the third law hold?

Comment: @MichaelWilliams If $E=N/2$, then $N_i = 0$ for all $i$, so I'm not sure what excited states you're referring to.

Comment: @J.Murray The system is at zero temperature. But the states of the system can still be highly excited while being in equilibrium. What is the contradiction here?

Comment: @MichaelWilliams There is precisely one state with $E=N/2$. Any excited states will have at least one $N_i >0$, which means that $E>N/2$, and so $T>0$.